# Block tridiagonal matrix python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I would like to create a block tridiagonal matrix starting from three numpy.ndarray.
Is there any (direct) way to do that in python?

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Do you want the result to be another ndarray, or are you open to using a sparse array for the result?

Comment: This question should be more precise and should provide a framing example.

Answer (score 35):

With "regular" numpy arrays, using [numpy.diag](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
def tridiag(a, b, c, k1=-1, k2=0, k3=1):
    return np.diag(a, k1) + np.diag(b, k2) + np.diag(c, k3)

a = [1, 1]; b = [2, 2, 2]; c = [3, 3]
A = tridiag(a, b, c)
```

Comment: This is plain tridiagonal, not "block tridiagonal" as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_tridiagonal_matrices or the desired matrix laid out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068800/creation-a-tridiagonal-block-matrix-in-python

Answer (score 13):

Use the function `scipy.sparse.diags`.

Example:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
import numpy as np

n = 10
k = [np.ones(n-1),-2*np.ones(n),np.ones(n-1)]
offset = [-1,0,1]
A = diags(k,offset).toarray()
```

This returns:

```
array([[-2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.]])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this with "regular" numpy arrays through fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros((10,10))
data[np.arange(5), np.arange(5)+2] = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
data[np.arange(3)+4, np.arange(3)] = [1, 2, 3]
print data
```

(You could replace those calls to `np.arange` with `np.r_` if you wanted to be more concise. E.g. instead of `data[np.arange(3)+4, np.arange(3)]`, use `data[np.r_[:3]+4, np.r_[:3]]`)

This yields:

```
[[0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

However, if you're going to be using sparse matrices anyway, have a look at [`scipy.sparse.spdiags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spdiags.html#scipy.sparse.spdiags).  (Note that you'll need to *prepend* fake data onto your row values if you're placing data into a diagonal position with a positive value (e.g. the 3's in position 4 in the example))

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse

diag_rows = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]])
positions = [-3, 0, 4]
print sp.sparse.spdiags(diag_rows, positions, 10, 10).todense()
```

This yields:

```
[[2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

*@TheCorwoodRep*'s answer can actually be done in a single line. No need for a seperate function.

```
np.eye(3,3,k=-1) + np.eye(3,3)*2 + np.eye(3,3,k=1)*3
```

This produces:

```
array([[ 2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

For building a block-wise tridiagonal matrix from the three individual blocks (and repeat the blocks for N times), one solution can be:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def tridiag(c, u, d, N): 
    # c, u, d are center, upper and lower blocks, repeat N times
    cc = block_diag(*([c]*N)) 
    shift = c.shape[1]
    uu = block_diag(*([u]*N)) 
    uu = np.hstack((np.zeros((uu.shape[0], shift)), uu[:,:-shift]))
    dd = block_diag(*([d]*N)) 
    dd = np.hstack((dd[:,shift:],np.zeros((uu.shape[0], shift))))
    return cc+uu+dd
```

For example:

```python
c = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,1]])
u = np.matrix([[2,2],[2,2]])
d = -1*u
N =4
H = tridiag(c,u,d,N)
print(H)
```

gives the answer

```python
[[ 1.  1.  2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-2. -2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  0.  0.]
 [-2. -2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -2. -2.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  0. -2. -2.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -2. -2.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -2. -2.  1.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

For better or worse, all the other answers seem to answer about tridiagonal matrices and not *block* tridiagonal matrices.

I don't think there is native support for tridiagonal matrices, so I wrote my own code. I had zeros on the main diagonal and my matrix was symmetric.

Here is my code.

```
n1 = 784
n2 = 256
n3 = 128
n4 = 10
M1 = np.ones((n1,n2))
M2 = np.ones((n2,n3))
M3 = np.ones((n3, n4))

def blockTri(Ms):
    #Takes in a list of matrices (not square) and returns a tridiagonal block matrix with zeros on the diagonal
    count = 0
    idx = []
    for M in Ms:
        #print(M.shape)
        count += M.shape[0]
        idx.append(count)
    count += Ms[-1].shape[-1]
    mat = np.zeros((count,count))
    count = 0
    for i, M in enumerate(Ms):
        mat[count:count+M.shape[0],idx[i]:idx[i]+M.shape[1]] = M
        count = count + M.shape[0]
    mat = mat + mat.T    
    return mat

M = blockTri([M1, M2, M3])
```

Hopefully this can help future people looking for *block* tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/a/62904889/1653571 answer uses the scipy.linag.block_diag() to paste the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

My answer builds of @TheCorwoodRep's answer. I am just posting it because I made a few changes to make it more modular so that it would work for different orders of matrices and also changing the values of `k1`,`k2`,`k3` i.e which decide where the diagonal appears, will take care of the overflow automatically. While calling the function you can specify what values should appear on the diagonals.

```
import numpy as np
def tridiag(T,x,y,z,k1=-1, k2=0, k3=1):
    a = [x]*(T-abs(k1)); b = [y]*(T-abs(k2)); c = [z]*(T-abs(k3))
    return np.diag(a, k1) + np.diag(b, k2) + np.diag(c, k3)

D=tridiag(10,-1,2,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tridiagonal matrix is a sparse matrix using a sparse package could be a nice option, see http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/spmatrix.html#matlab-implementation, there are some examples and comparisons with MATLAB even...

Answer (score 0):

I just needed something similar. I share my workaround too.

```
from  functools import reduce
import numpy as np
size = 5
vals = [1,3,4]
res = reduce(lambda a, b: a+np.eye(size,k=b[0])*b[1], enumerate(vals), np.zeros((size, size)))
print(res)
# [[1. 3. 4. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 3. 4. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 3. 4.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1. 3.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

```
size = 7
vals = [1,3,4,7,6]
offset = -2
res = reduce(lambda a, b: a+np.eye(size,k=b[0]+offset)*b[1], enumerate(vals), np.zeros((size, size)))
print(res)
# [[4. 7. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 4. 7. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 3. 4. 7. 6. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 3. 4. 7. 6. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 3. 4. 7. 6.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1. 3. 4. 7.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 3. 4.]]
```