# Replace all off diagonal elements in numpy array

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I have below `numpy` array

```
import numpy as np
np.identity(13)
```

Now I like to replace all off-diagonal elements with some other number, say 0.45.

Is there any direct method available to perform this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In matrix of 100 x 100 in python, filling the off diagonal elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651432/in-matrix-of-100-x-100-in-python-filling-the-off-diagonal-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
np.where(np.identity(13)==0, 0.45, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```py
import numpy as np
n = 13
val_offdiag = 0.45
val_diag = 1
a = np.full((n ,n), val_offdiag) - np.identity(n) * (val_offdiag - val_diag)
```