# Build diagonal matrix without using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, diagonal

I am trying to build the following matrix in Python without using a `for` loop:

```
A 
 [[ 0.1  0.2  0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   2.   3.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   1.   2.   3.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   1.   2.   3. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   4.   5. ]]
```

I tried the `fill_diagonal` method in NumPy (see matrix B below) but it does not give me the same matrix as shown in matrix A:

```
B 
 [[ 1.   0.2  0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   2.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   3.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   1.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   4.   5. ]]
```

Here is the Python code that I used to construct the matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as sp   # maybe use scipy to build diagonal matrix?

#---- build diagonal square array using "for" loop
m = 5

A = np.zeros((m, m))

A[0, 0] = 0.1
A[0, 1] = 0.2

for i in range(1, m-1):
    A[i, i-1] = 1   # m-1
    A[i, i] = 2     # m
    A[i, i+1] = 3   # m+1

A[m-1, m-2] = 4
A[m-1, m-1] = 5

print('A \n', A)

#---- build diagonal square array without loop
B = np.zeros((m, m))

B[0, 0] = 0.1
B[0, 1] = 0.2

np.fill_diagonal(B, [1, 2, 3])

B[m-1, m-2] = 4
B[m-1, m-1] = 5

print('B \n', B)
```

So is there a way to construct a diagonal matrix like the one shown by matrix A without using a `for` loop?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842903/block-tridiagonal-matrix-python). This looks like a tridiagonal matrix to me.

Comment: @flebool That question does not have an accepted answer. The suggestions also seem to have the same problem that I am having with the diagonal. I am also not trying to use a user defined function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are functions for this in `scipy.sparse`, e.g.:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags

C = diags([1,2,3], [-1,0,1], shape=(5,5), dtype=float)

C = C.toarray()

C[0, 0] = 0.1
C[0, 1] = 0.2
C[-1, -2] = 4
C[-1, -1] = 5
```

Diagonal matrices are generally very sparse, so you could also keep it as a sparse matrix. This could even have large efficiency benefits, depending on the application.

---

The efficiency gains sparse matrices could give you depend very much on matrix size. For a 5x5 array you can't really be bothered I guess. But for larger matrices creating the array *could* be a lot faster with sparse matrices, illustrated by the following example with an identity matrix:

```
%timeit np.eye(3000)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.12 ms per loop

%timeit sparse.eye(3000)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 79.5 µs per loop
```

But the real strength of the sparse matrix data type is shown when you need to do mathematical operations on arrays that are sparse:

```
%timeit np.eye(3000).dot(np.eye(3000))
# 1 loops, best of 3: 2.8 s per loop

%timeit sparse.eye(3000).dot(sparse.eye(3000))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
```

Or when you need to work with some very large but sparse array:

```
np.eye(1E6)
# ValueError: array is too big.

sparse.eye(1E6)
# <1000000x1000000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
# with 1000000 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of the `toarray()` function?

Comment: @Gavin. The function `diags` creates an instance of a `scipy.sparse` matrix, specifically a `dia_matrix` in this case, though you can get other types by giving the right keyword argument. The method `toarray` converts the sparse matrix to a  standard numpy array which is much more flexible and prints prettier. The `dia_matrix` type doesn't even allow single item assignment for example .

Comment: You can also use `diags` as `a = diags([[1, 1, 1, 4], [0.1, 2, 2, 2, 5], [0.2, 3, 3, 3]], [-1, 0, 1])`.  See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html

Comment: This approach seems to work, although I'm not sure if there is any efficiency gained compared to the `for` loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the number of `0` is always 3 (or a constant whenever you want to have a diagonal matrix like this):

```
In [10]:    
import numpy as np
A1=[0.1, 0.2]
A2=[1,2,3]
A3=[4,5]
SPC=[0,0,0] #=or use np.zeros #spacing zeros
np.hstack((A1,SPC,A2,SPC,A2,SPC,A2,SPC,A3)).reshape(5,5)
Out[10]:
array([[ 0.1,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  4. ,  5. ]])
```

---

```
In [11]:    
import itertools #A more general way of doing it
np.hstack(list(itertools.chain(*[(item, SPC) for item in [A1, A2, A2, A2, A3]]))[:-1]).reshape(5,5)
Out[11]:
array([[ 0.1,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  4. ,  5. ]])
```