# Python creating matrix using if condition on indices : incorrect result

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have the following code where I have been trying to create a tridiagonal matrix `x` using `if`-conditions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import useful modules
import numpy as np


N=5
x=np.identity(N)
#x=np.zeros((N,N))
print x

# Construct NxN matrix 
for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
        if i-j==1:
            x[i][j]=1 
        elif j-1==1:
            x[i][j]=-1
        else:
            x[i][j]=0

            print "i= ",i," j= ",j          


print x
```

I desire to  get

```
[[ 0.  -1. 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  -1  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

However, I obtain

```
[[ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  1.  0.]]
```

What's going wrong?

Bonus question : Can I forcefully index from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4 in this example, or Python never allows that?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `j-i == 1`?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842903/block-tridiagonal-matrix-python for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif j-1==1:` should be `elif j-i==1:`.

And no, lists/arrays etc. are always indexed from `0`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do such a mistake? I'm voting to delete my post. Extremely sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As for the bonus question, **the first element of a sequence in Python has always the index 0**. However, if for some particular reason (for example to prevent off-by-one errors) you wish to count the elements of a sequence from a value other than 0, you could use the built-in function [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and set the value of the optional parameter `start` to fit your needs:

```py
>>> seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for count, item in enumerate(seq, start=1):
...     print(count, item)
...
1 a
2 b
3 c
```