# Block tridiagonal matrices, how to program this kind of matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

We consider `h=1/(n+1)` and `n>=1`. We consider a matrix `K` such as :

[image]

and the matrix `L = 1/h² Id`, where `Id` is the identity matrix.

We would like to program the matrix `A` :

[image]

I can program `K` and `L`, but how to program `A`? A is a matrix composed of matrices. How to implement this in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block tridiagonal matrix python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842903/block-tridiagonal-matrix-python)

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt It doesn't look like a dupe to me. This is asking for a genuine block matrix while linked OP doesn't seem to know what a block matrix actually is.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right.  I think I may have misread OP.

Comment: scipy.sparse now has a `block_diag` function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html.  You may need to create a `K -L/-L K` subblock first.  sparse block assembly uses the `coo` sparse format to define a new sparse matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are open to `numpy`/`scipy` (recommended):

Use `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` to create banded matrices and `numpy.kron` to create patterns of repeated blocks:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

h = 10
K = np.zeros((4,))
K[:2] = (4 / h**2, -1 / h**2)

K = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(K)

L = np.identity(4) / h**2

KK = np.identity(3)

LL = scipy.linalg.toeplitz((0, -1, 0))

A = np.kron(LL, L) + np.kron(KK, K)

# array([[ 0.04, -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [-0.01,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  , -0.01,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [-0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [-0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04, -0.01,  0.  ],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04, -0.01],
#        [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.  , -0.01,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.01,  0.04]])
```

If it has to be pure Python:

Make a matrix of matrices and the use `zip` to transpose the middle dimensions and flat list comprehension to make 2D.

```
K = [[0.04 if i==j else -0.01 if i-j in {-1, 1} else 0.0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

L = [[-0.01 if i==j else 0.0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

Z = [[0.0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

# matrix of matrices
A = [[K if i==j else L if i-j in {-1, 1} else Z for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]

# make 2d
A = [[a_IJij for a_IJi in a_Ii for a_IJij in a_IJi] for a_I in A for a_Ii in zip(*a_I)]

for a in A:
    print(' '.join(f'{i:5.2f}' for i in a))

#  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
# -0.01  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
#  0.00 -0.01  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
#  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
# -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00
#  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00
#  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00
#  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01
#  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.04 -0.01  0.00  0.00
#  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04 -0.01  0.00
#  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04 -0.01
#  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [numpy.eye](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) function to get an identity matrix with ones on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else.  You can use the optional parameter `k=x` to specify the offset for the diagonal.  If you multiply these identity matrices by a scalar, you'll be able to introduce the `L` and `K`.  Add the matrices together to get the tri-diagonal matrix that you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 4, 4
L = 1
K = 4
A = np.eye(m, n, k=-1) * (-L) + np.eye(m, n) * K + np.eye(m, n, k=1) * (-L)
```