# Creation a tridiagonal block matrix in python

Tags: python

[image]

How can I create this matrix using python ?

I've already created S , T , X ,W ,Y and Z as well as the first and the last line of L.

Comment: The question here is better written than the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842903/block-tridiagonal-matrix-python in that it shows an example of the desired matrix.  It is clearly asking for something different than a matrix with three scalar diagonals.  It is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_tridiagonal_matrices and might have some guidance in this neglected answer to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241451/1653571

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (it's a draft!). Make a class that stores 3 lists (diagonal, upper diagonal and lower diagonal) and expose a way of editing those values.

```
class TBMatrix:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self._size = size #Has to be square I guess?
        self._diagonal = [None for i in range(0,size)]
        self._upper_diagonal = [None for i in range(0,size - 2)]
        self._lower_diagonal = [None for i in range(0,size - 2)]
    def get(self,row,col):
        if row == col:
            return self._diagonal[row]
        if row == col - 1:
            return self._lower_diagonal[col]
        if row == col + 1:
            return self._upper_diagonal[row]
        return 0 #or None, if you want a matrix that contains objects 
    def set(self,row,col,value):
        if row == col:
            self._diagonal[row] = value
        elif row == col - 1:
            self._lower_diagonal[col] = value
        elif row == col + 1:
            self._upper_diagonal[row] = value
        else:
            #No effect, maybe you want to throw an exception?
            pass
```

This is a quick draft, you'll need to do a bunch of checks to make sure there is no trying to assign an index outside of the list sizes. But this should get you started.

Another alternative is to override the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to return a row full of 0's or `None` except where it need to hold a spot for `self._diagonal`, `self._upper_diagonal` and `self._lower_diagonal`. But it just seems more complicated.